# How to 'avoid' application not responding when big elaboration are made?

Tags: .net

When i lunch a function on my .net application, the app seems to be "blocked". So i ask you: how can *limit* cpu workload for a particular method ? 
The only way is the Application.DoEvents ?
And: what if i use an third party dll that for the same reason (big elaboration) seems to block (not responding) my app ?

EDIT: maybe threading is the answer, but, now, i've another question: is it possible to 'limit' cpu usage to a thread ?

Comment: limitng CPU usage will not help your "not responding issue"

Comment: Trying to limit cpu usage will just make it block *longer*.  Use BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to 'avoid' application not responding when big elaboration are made?

Run whatever is causing the blocking on a different thread than the main thread.

> how can limit cpu workload for a particular method ?

You can't limit it for a particular method. Only for a particular thread. And this will not solve the blocking issue.

> maybe threading is the answer

No, not *maybe*. It *is* the answer.

> but, now, i've another question: is it possible to 'limit' cpu usage to a thread ?

Well, you could *try* setting `Thread.Priority`. Note that the OS does not have to honor the priority that you set (thus, *try*). Additionally, this just changes the priority for scheduling the thread to execute. If there are no other threads that need CPU time, then of course your thread will still get scheduled on the CPU.